# Test class for updated field value

Tags: unit-test, class, failing-tests

I have a class that is scheduled using CRON. I have created a test class and the test for the CRON is tested ok. However, the field update is not being tested and I cannot see why. Coverage is 57% with 4/6 
pass. Could anyone help? thanks

Class.

```java
global class ScheduleEmailInvoices implements Schedulable {


global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {


List<Email_Notifications__c > acclist = [Select SendStatus__c,QualifyDate__c from Email_Notifications__c where SendStatus__c = 'Completed' and QualifyDate__c =Today];


        for(Email_Notifications__c a: acclist)

        {

               a.SendStatus__c = 'Ready to send';

        }
        update acclist;

 }
}
```

Test Class.

```java
@isTest
private class ScheduleEmailInvoicesTest {

    static testMethod void myTestMethod() {

    test.starttest(); 

    ScheduleEmailInvoices myClass = new ScheduleEmailInvoices ();   
    String chron = '0 00 07 * * ?';        
    system.schedule('Schedule Email InvoicesTest', chron, myClass);
    system.assert([SELECT COUNT() FROM CronTrigger] > 0);

   test.stopTest();


    }

 static testMethod void validateStatus() {
 Email_Notifications__c b = new Email_Notifications__c(Name='test', SendStatus__c ='Completed',QualifyDate__c = system.today());


 Test.startTest();
 // Insert record
 insert b;

 Test.stopTest();


 b = [SELECT SendStatus__c FROM Email_Notifications__c WHERE Id =:b.Id];



 System.assertEquals('Ready to send', b.SendStatus__c);
 }


}
```

Comment: What specific problem you are facing here?

Comment: the update to status is being highlighted as a fail in the test;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do this in a single test. Data processed by one test method is not available to another. Each method has its separate transaction.

1. Insert the test records.
2. Schedule the job, after the `startest()`.
3. Query the result and assert after the `stopTest()`.

Comment: ok. I will try that. thanks Rahul

Comment: perfect. Thanks again Rahul

Comment: @user2382031 please mark as accepted if it works for you.

Comment: ok. just accepted. can I score your response. Sorry not sure how

Comment: @user2382031 thank! I think not as of now, you need to reach specific reputations for that. Which you can gain by asking good questions and answering other people's questions. happy coding!

Comment: ok thanks again

Comment: hi, my new test class passes in Dev 100% but fails 0% in Production. I am unable to post the class in comments as it is tool long

Comment: @user2382031 There must be something different in the product. Check my [blog post](https://sftrailmixer.blogspot.com/2019/12/troubleshoot-test-failure-in-salesforce.html) on how to troubleshoot this.

Comment: thanks Rahul, will do. How do I set up and view debug logs in Production?